# Does AudioTrack buffer need to be full always in streaming mode?

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to figure out some latency issues with the Android `AudioTrack`, and documentation is very scarce. Two question I have in particular are

1. Does an `AudioTrack` object need its buffer full before it starts playing audio, which would indicate that minimum latency one can get in (minimum buffer length) / (sampling rate)? Does it alternatively start playing immediately the first chunk of samples have been given to it? Is there a way to check how full the buffer is before it starts playing?
2. Secondly, when exactly does `AudioTrack` block?

Comment: Some quick experimentation suggests that (1) AudioTrack won't play anything if you don't fill its buffer and (2) AudioTrack.write() starts blocking as soon as the buffer is full. So I am left wondering how to avoid blocking, and how to ensure that all the audio that I want to play gets played -- without unnecessary latency. Yo Google! Write more documentation! Come to think of it, virtually all the APIs could benefit from more documentation. See also http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3434

Comment: All the on-line examples show the audio writes being executed from a background thread.

Comment: @EdwardFalk probably because the writes are blocking