# AudioTrack not playing samples at button clicked sometimes

Tags: android, audiotrack

My android OS is Android M. Nexus 6. 
I implemented a `AndroidSpeakerWriter` as

```
public class AndroidSpeakerWriter {

    private final static String TAG= "AndroidSpeakerWriter";

    private AudioTrack audioTrack;

    short[] buffer;

    public AndroidSpeakerWriter() {
        buffer = new short[1024];
    }


    public void init(int sampleRateInHZ){
        int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRateInHZ,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRateInHZ,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM); // 0-static 1-stream
    }   

    public void fillBuffer(short[] samples) {
        if (buffer.length<samples.length) {
            buffer = new short[samples.length];
        }
        System.arraycopy(samples, 0, buffer, 0, samples.length);
    }

    public void writeSamples(short[] samples) {
        fillBuffer(samples);
        audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, samples.length);
    }

    public void stop() {
        audioTrack.stop();
    }

    public void play() {
        audioTrack.play();
     }
}
```

Then I just send samples when I click a button

```
public void play(final short[] signal) {
    if (signal == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "play: a null signal");
        return;
    }
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            android.os.Process
                    .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
            androidSpeakerWriter.play();
            androidSpeakerWriter.writeSamples(signal);
            androidSpeakerWriter.stop();
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

The problem is the device does not beep every time I click the button.
Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.
There is no such a problem when I run this on an old nexus galaxy phone android 4.3. Anybody has encountered a similar problem? Thanks in advance for any help.

One thing is that currently my beep is pretty short (256 samples), not even close to the `minBufferSize`.

The `bufferSizeInBytes` in the constructor of `AudioTrack` for static mode should be the audio sample length you wanna play according to the vague [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html). 
So is it still has a minimal size constraint on the buffer even for static mode? Why a nexus galaxy can play a 256 sample audio in static mode and a nexus 6 can not.

I  use `AudioManager` to get the native buffer size/ sampling rate
nexus galaxy: 144/44100  nexus 6: 192/48000

I found those related:

- [AudioRecord and AudioTrack latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379063/audiorecord-and-audiotrack-latency/6905575#6905575)
- [Does AudioTrack buffer need to be full always in streaming mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904265/does-audiotrack-buffer-need-to-be-full-always-in-streaming-mode)
- https://github.com/igorski/MWEngine/wiki/Understanding-Android-audio-towards-achieving-low-latency-response

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is caused by improper synchronization between thread. Your `androidSpeakerWriter` instance is running continously in different thread calling `play()`, `writeSamples()`, `stop()` respectively. Click of button will trigger creation of new thread with same `androidSpeakerWriter` instance.

So while Thread A is executing `androidSpeakerWriter.play()`, Thread B might be executing `androidSpeakerWriter.writeSamples()` which might overwrite current audio data being played.

Try

```
synchronized(androidSpeakerWriter) {
        androidSpeakerWriter.play();
        androidSpeakerWriter.writeSamples(signal);
        androidSpeakerWriter.stop();
}
```

`MODE_STREAM` is used if you must play long audio data that will not fit into memory. If you need to play short audio file such beep sound, you can use `MODE_STATIC` when creating AudioTrack. then change your playback code such following:

```
synchronized(androidSpeakerWriter) {
        androidSpeakerWriter.writeSamples(signal);
        androidSpeakerWriter.play();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried. It does not help much. The interesting thing is that when i run the same app on another device. There is no such problem.